# Webpack prematurely compiles watched files

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Webpack is running with the --watch option, but it compiles files before I press Save in Webstorm or hit `Ctrl` `S`.

**How can I disable this premature compiling?**

I'm using webpack and WebStorm on Windows 10. (No File Watchers specified in Webstorm). I'm also using the `OldWatchingPlugin` because it's much faster. The behavior is also present when using the standard watching plugin.

Comment: Do you have "safe write" enabled? If so, try disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [bebraw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/228885/bebraw), I found the answer in Webstorm settings as shown below. 
[image: Webstorm settings]